# Find and replace some elements in a list using python

Tags: python, list, indexing, replace, find

I have to search all elements in a list and replace all occurrences of one element with another. What is the best way to do this?

For example, suppose my list has the following elements:

```
data = ['a34b3f8b22783cf748d8ec99b651ddf35204d40c',
        'baa6cb4298d90db1c375c63ee28733eb144b7266',
        'CommitTest.txt',
        '=>',
        'text/CommitTest.txt',
        '0',
        'README.md',
        '=>',
        'text/README.md',
        '0']
```

and I need to replace all occurrences of character '=>' with the combined value from elements before and after the character '=>', so the output I need is:

```
data = ['a34b3f8b22783cf748d8ec99b651ddf35204d40c',
        'baa6cb4298d90db1c375c63ee28733eb144b7266',
        'CommitTest.txt=>text/CommitTest.txt',
        '0',
        'README.md=>text/README.md',
        '0']
```

This is my code I wrote so far:

```
ind = data.index("=>")
item_to_replace = data[ind]
combine = data[ind-1]+data[ind]+data[ind+1]
replacement_value = combine
indices_to_replace = [i for i,x in enumerate(data) if x==item_to_replace]

for i in indices_to_replace:
    data[i] = replacement_value

data
```

However, the unwanted output is like this :

```
data = ['a34b3f8b22783cf748d8ec99b651ddf35204d40c',
        'baa6cb4298d90db1c375c63ee28733eb144b7266',
        'CommitTest.txt',
        'CommitTest.txt=>text/CommitTest.txt',
        'text/CommitTest.txt',
        '0',
        'README.md',
        'CommitTest.txt=>text/CommitTest.txt',
        'text/README.md',
        '0']
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: I don't really understand. Is the "unwanted" output is what actually should be according to your initial requirements? If you want to replace '=>' with previous and next values combined?

Comment: @Nurjan - the unwanted output means the output resulted from the code I wrote. But the output is not what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @alpha_989 suggested first find the index of `=>` element and replace for each occurances, hope this may help

```
>>> indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(data) if x == "=>"]
>>> for i in indices: #this will add one index upper and one index lower of elem "=>" with elem
        data[i-1] = data[i-1]+ data[i] + data[i+1] 
>>> for elem in data:
        if elem == "=>":
            del data[data.index("=>")+1]
            del data[data.index("=>")]
>>> data
['a34b3f8b22783cf748d8ec99b651ddf35204d40c', 'baa6cb4298d90db1c375c63ee28733eb144b7266', 'CommitTest.txt=>text/CommitTest.txt', '0', 'README.md=>text/README.md', '0']
```

Comment: This does not work, it fails to delete the value after the '=>'. If you really want an asnwer that mutates the list, you need to add `del data[data.index("=>") + 1]`

Answer (score 2):

Your general algorithm is correct.

However, data.index("->") will only find the index of the first occurance of "->".

You need to find all occurrences of "=>" store it in a list, combine the elements and replace for each of the occurances.

To find the index of all occurance of "=>", you can use:

```
indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(data) if x == "=>"]
```

Answer (score 1):

It was correctly pointed out to you that `data.index` will only return the index of the first occurence of an element. Furthermore, you code does not remove the entries after and before the `"=>"`.

For a solution that mutates your list, you could use `del`, but I recommend using this neat slicing syntax that Python offers.

```
indices = [i for i, val in enumerate(data) if val == '=>']

for i in reversed(indices):
    data[i-1: i+2] = [data[i-1] + data[i] + data[i+1]]
```

I also suggest you attempt an implementation that generates a new list in a single pass. Mutating a list can be a bad practice and has no real advantage over creating a new list like so.

```
new_data = []
i = 0

while i < len(data):
    if i + 1 < len(data) and data[i + 1] == "=>":
        new_data.append(data[i] + data[i+1] + data[i+2])
        i += 3
    else:
        new_data.append(data[i])
        i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is my little experiment, I added a function to call. You can check for it:

```
data = ['a34b3f8b22783cf748d8ec99b651ddf35204d40c',
            'baa6cb4298d90db1c375c63ee28733eb144b7266',
            'CommitTest.txt',
            '=>',
            'text/CommitTest.txt',
            '0',
            'README.md',
            '=>',
            'text/README.md',
            '0']


def convert_list():
    ind = [i for i, x in enumerate(data) if x == "=>"]

    if ind == 0 or ind == len(data) - 1:
        print("Invalid element location")
        return

    new_data = []

    index_start = 0
    while index_start < len(data):
        for ind_index in ind:
            if index_start == ind_index -1:
                index_start += 3
                new_data.append(data[ind_index - 1] + data[ind_index] +data[ind_index + 1])

            new_data.append(data[index_start])
            index_start += 1

    return new_data

print(convert_list())
```

Answer (score 0):

The indexs that need to be deleted are saved first, then deleted.

```
delete_index=[]
for i,d in enumerate(data):
    if(d=="=>"):
        data[i]=data[i-1]+data[i]+data[i+1]
        delete_index.append(i-1)
        delete_index.append(i+1)
new_data=[]
for i,d in enumerate(data):
    if i not in delete_index:
        new_data.append(d)
print(new_data)
```